# Python import installed package instead from local folder

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-import

When I in any folder

```
python3
import a.b
```

works OK

When I in folder with files:

```
- a
-- c.py
```

and I try

```
python3
import a.b
```

I got **No module named a.b**

I understand, why, but now I want other. How avoid this?
Rename is inpossible, b is plugin for a and installed separately

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what level you are in the file structure, but I ran into this problem a while back and I'm pretty sure explicitly stating the import fixed the problem. Try using "from a import b" and if that doesn't work you can try a relative import "from . import b" lmk if this works for you.

Comment: As I understand, OP has installed package named **a**. Unfortunately, there's also a subdirectory in their cwd that is also named **a**. How to import from **a** (installed), instead of **a** (subdirectory)? I fail to see how this answer is appropriately answering that.